# Sending Json with github log to post message slack through github action

Tags: json, github-actions, slack, slack-block-kit

```
{
  "content": [
    {
      "commit": "testing",
      "subject": "testing",
      "author": {
        "name": "testing",
        "email": "testing",
        "date": "testing"
      }
    },
    {
      "commit": "testing",
      "subject": "testing",
      "author": {
        "name": "testing",
        "email": "testing",
        "date": "testing"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to send this data format to slack with slackapi/slack-github-action@v1.18.0?

Preferable in some nice format using block kit

I have tried to sent the information in JSON but either it was an error like not a valid JSON or no_text

Obtain data:

```
PENDING_PR=$(git log --pretty=format:'{%n  "commit": "%H",%n "subject": "%s",%n "author": {%n    "name": "%aN",%n    "email": "%aE",%n    "date": "%aD"%n  }%n},' origin/blabla...feature/blabla | sed "$ s/,$//" | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\r\n\([^{]\)/\\n\1/g'| awk 'BEGIN { print("[") } { print($0) } END { print("]") }')  >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

Sent in slackapi/slack-github-action@v1.18.0

```
      steps:
      - name: Send Slack message when release is unsuccessful
        uses: slackapi/slack-github-action@v1.18.0
        with:
        # For posting a rich message using Block Kit
          payload: |
            {
             "blocks": [
                 {
                   "type": "section",
                   "text": {
                     "type": "mrkdwn",
                     "text": "${{ fromJSON(needs.testing.outputs.PENDING_PR) }}"
                  }
                 }
              ]
             }
        env:
          SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL: ${{ secrets.SLACK_WEBHOOK }}
          SLACK_WEBHOOK_TYPE: INCOMING_WEBHOOK
```

error:

````
{
  content: [
    {
      commit: 'test',
      subject: 'test',
      author: [Object]
    },
    {
      commit: 'test',
      subject: 'test)',
      author: [Object]
    },
    {
      commit: 'test',
      subject: 'test',
      author: [Object]
    },
    {
      commit: 'test',
      subject: 'test',
      author: [Object]
    }
  ]
}
Error: no_text
Error: Request failed with status code 400```
````

Comment: What is the value of `PENDING_PR` before adding it to `text`? Have you verified that the final JSON for validity?

Comment: I have actually tried to sent it as payload JSON

`payload      { ${{ needs.testing.outputs.PENDING_PR }} }`

`
      - name: Send Slack message when release is unsuccessful
        uses: slackapi/slack-github-action@v1.18.0
        with:
        # For posting a rich message using Block Kit
          payload: |
            {
              ${{ needs.testing.outputs.PENDING_PR }}
            }
`

Comment: And, it failed?

Comment: Please include a sample that `PENDING_PR` holds in your question.

Comment: Error: no_text
Error: Request failed with status code 400

Comment: The JSON in the question is the data of PENDING_PR

Comment: But it is also possible to adjust the output of the PENDING_PR if that is needed to sent the message to slack successfully

Comment: Without an actual sample of `PENDING_PR` it is hard to say why this is happening. It could just be a simple JSON syntax error.

Comment: Please see update request + error in the original question

Comment: Thanks! The value of `PENDING_PR` should be string literal with `text` or it should be expanded to another JSON object?

Comment: In their docs they have following example:

  `uses: slackapi/slack-github-action@v1.23.0`
  `with:`
    `payload:`
      `{`
        `"key": "value",`
        `"foo": "bar"`
      `}`

https://github.com/slackapi/slack-github-action

Comment: If this is a JSON i.e. the value of `PENDING_PR`, the keys are not quoted and the value `Object` inside `[]` should be a proper JSON literal. You might want to add a separate step to validate the JSON before sending it.

Comment: Maybe, this is what you actually wanted: https://jqplay.org/s/xay3Oy6HEF7.

Comment: let me try that

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved:

valid payload which has to be sent to API must look like

```
payload: 
{ "blocks": 
 [ 
  { "type":"section", 
    "text":{ 
      "type":"mrkdwn", 
      "text":"some text" }
    }
  ]
}
```

thanks @azeem

Comment: You're welcome! Is this the final config that worked? I believe you're missing `|` with `payload`.